# Remove special characters of html using perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to remove HTML special symbols using perl. I tried using this HTML::Strip, Encode qw( _utf8_on);

```
use Encode qw( _utf8_on );
_utf8_on($string);
print "$string\n\n";

Output: Clearance Subject Male control 5 1-a 21 31â Â±â2 74

use HTML::Strip;
my $hs = HTML::Strip->new();
my $clean_text = $hs->parse($string);
print "$clean_text\n";

Ouput: Clearance Subject Male control 5 1-a 21 31Ã¢ ÃÂ±Ã¢2 74

Expected output: Clearance Subject Male control 5 1-a 21 31±2 74
```

Can some one help me in this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: May I see where does `$string` come from?

Comment: So ``HTML::Strip`` is working as it should, right? In that case, you could leave it out of the snippet. But apart from that, exactly what else is it that you want to remove from the string? Is it invalid UTF-8 chars?

Comment: $string="Clearance Subject Male control 5 1-a 21 31Ã¢ ÃÂ±Ã¢2 74"; This way I declared $string

Comment: This has no HTML markup inside, so why would `HTML::strip` change the string?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, NEVER use `_utf8_on`. If you want to decode a string, use Encode's `decode_utf8` or the builtin `utf8::encode`. (The latter works in-place.)

---

Now on the answer.

(Just got a second, so I can't verify my guess at the answer.)

You need to pass raw HTML (as the docs say) to `parse`, not some decoded version of it. Adding `utf8::downgrade($string);` before `$hs->parse($string);` will detect some errors on your part and it will work around a rarely occurring bug in HTML::Strip.

If you do this and your original string is an HTML document containing

```
...Clearance Subject Male control 5 1-a 21 31±2 74...
```

you should get the following for output:

```
...Clearance Subject Male control 5 1-a 21 31±2 74...
```